# Inserting string value using substring not returning intended output

Tags: javascript, concatenation

This simple program I am making, `solution`, isn't returning the intended output.

If the `string` includes the phrase `camelCasing` the expected output should be `camel Casing`. If the `string` includes any other words like `camelCasingCarrier` the output should be `camel Casing Carrier`.

If the `string` includes any other phrase, it should just return the `string`.

```
function solution(string) {
  let newString = null;
  let stringToAdd = ' '
  if (string.includes('camelCasing')) {
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      let letter = string[i];
      if (letter == letter.toUpperCase()) {
        newString = string.substring(0, letter) + stringToAdd + string.substring(letter);
      }
    }
    return newString;
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
```

My current output is  `camelCasingCarrier` with a space at the beginning rather than the expected output. What is my issue and how should I fix this? Thanks again :)

Comment: Each time through the loop you overwrite the changes to `newString` that you made on the previous iteration.

Comment: You need to accumulate characters in `newString`, not overwrite it completely.

Comment: I see I see, should I then accumulate characters into an array and then join them together into a string? @Barmar

Comment: string.substring takes numeric arguments, but `letter` is a letter.  Maybe you meant to use `i`?

Comment: You can accumulate into a string. Initialize `newString = ''` then use `newString +=` to add to it.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, thank you :)

Comment: If you have an answer you should post as an answer, don't edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

The substring method `string.substring(start, end)` takes up to two arguments, integer numbers that must be the index range of the string, to generate a substring from.
In your case you are using a letter (`letter`) as an argument and this won't work. If you use the index `i` instead of `letter` it would work, but only for a single replacement and not for "camelCasingCarrier" for example.

As you already mentioned, the best solution is to avoid using the `substring` method and simply add a space before the capital letters as you parse over the string:

```
function solution(string) {
  let newString = '';
  if (string.includes('camelCasing')) {
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      let letter = string[i];
      if (letter == letter.toUpperCase()) {
        newString += ' ' + letter;
      } else {
        newString += letter;
      }
    }
    return newString;
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you called attention to what the original problem was and how your solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I added more info.